# Where can I stay once I get a private visa invitation from my Russian friend

Tags: visas, russia, airbnb, french-citizens

When my Russian friend invites me to Russia, will he have to specify that I (the person coming to visit) will have to stay at his personal residence? Can that be specified as elsewhere (such as an Airbnb location)?

In the scenario where he has to specify his address, am I required to stay at my friends place once I get the private visa? or will I be able to choose a specific place from Airbnb?

*I'm from France if that changes anything*